# How to profile ViewHierarchy on the real device and get absolute timings?

Tags: android, android-layout, hierarchyviewer

[Official reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer-results-walkthru.html#InterpretingResults) clearly defines that profiler messages are relative and measured on the hosted cpu. It also says

> This means that the absolute reported timings are correct relative to each other, but are bloated and vary depending on the overall and changing CPU workload on your device and PC.

**The question**
What should I do, to get the absolute timings? How to profile view hierarchy on the real device?

Comment: Android Studio's Layout Inspector works with hardware, though I haven't looked to see if this performance information is part of its output. Also, Hierarchy View itself works on hardware as of Android 4.2 or so.